# How to open file with default application in cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to open a file in it's default editor after the user has created the file. So far my script is:

```
@echo off
@echo --- Create A New File ---
@echo -
@echo Where should we put the new file?
set /p fileLocation=@ %UserProfile%\
@echo -
@echo What do you want to call your new file?
set /p fileName=@ 
@echo -
@echo Almost Done! What is the files extension?
set /p extension=@ .
@echo -
copy NUL "%UserProfile%\%fileLocation%\%fileName%.%extension%"
```

(ignore the extra echos and '@' those are just for fun)

After I click the file, it does the command: `Choose Location > Choose File Name > Choose File extension`. I'm almost done on what I want but theres one last thing. How can I get the file name that I created and then open in its default text-editor?

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051864/how-to-get-the-default-application-mapped-to-a-file-extention-in-windows-using-p

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `start` to open the file with the associated application.

---

**Resources :**

- [Open a File in the Default Application using the Windows Command Line (without JDIC)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101030061633/http://frank.neatstep.com/node/84) (waybackmachine capture from Oct 30, 2010)

Comment: How can I get the created file and then use that?

Comment: You already have your file name, its `"%UserProfile%\%fileLocation%\%fileName%.%extension%"` so just start it.

Comment: in your script; `start "%UserProfile%\%fileLocation%\%fileName%.%extension%"`.

Comment: Added at the end, it opens up another cmd, not the file.

Comment: Then you should use `assoc` before to associate an extension to a file type and `ftype` to associate a file type to an application.

Comment: can you put that together for me? I really do not understand it :( thanks so much for helping

Comment: `assoc .myExt = MyNewFileType` and `FTYPE MyNewFileType=C:\NotePad.exe` will associate the ".myExt" extension to NotePad.exe, if you do `start anyFile.myExt` it will open it in NotePad.exe

Comment: How would I insert that in the script?

Comment: The thing is you can't really do that. You must know the file type association before starting your application. So you must manually execute these commands to do the association first. Then you'll be able to call the start method anytime

Comment: Hm, how about.. get the fileLocation that I entered and then use the start command?

Comment: If it didn't work, it's because your file extension wasn't associated with an application, not because of your file location

Answer (score 24):

In windows you can use `start` (http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

```
start "" "%UserProfile%\%fileLocation%\%fileName%.%extension%"
```

Comment: Newcommers: note the empty quotes. It is required, and will not work other way.

Comment: It should... `start "" "path\file.extension" || notepad.exe "path\file.extension"`

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `explorer.exe`/`explorer` to open the file (e.g. `explorer file.txt`). This also works nicely if you use WSL, especially with an alias like `alias open="explorer.exe"` so you can just call it like, e.g., `open file.txt`.

Comment: I was using a lot this procedure (also from Cobol) but I saw that for every run it creates a new explorer.exe process and probably won't close when exiting the application. Check TaskManager.

Comment: Hm, that's not the case for me. I tried opening several files this way, and I didn't see any explorer.exe processes in task manager.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the correct way of FILE ASSOCIATION using these cmd commands. 
this is just an example:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe\shell\open\command" /v @ /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\\Program Files\\Noteepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\"" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt" /v "Application" /t REG_SZ /d "notepad++.exe" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithList" /v "g" /t REG_SZ /d "notepad++.exe" /f

assoc .txt=MyCustomType
ftype MyCustomType="C:\Program Files\Noteepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

(it's better to put them in .bat file)